# Creating the container of smart pointers by cloning elements of another container

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdset

I have a class, which supports cloning (via method `clone`). I have a bunch of its instances in a vector of `std::unique_ptr`.

Now, I want to create an `std::set` of same smart pointers from the above vector, ideally during its construction. The obvious design is as following:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    /// type of itself
    typedef A self;
    A() = default;
    A(const self& another) = default;
    virtual ~A() = default;

    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_unique<A>();
    }
};

class SetOfA
{
public:
    SetOfA() = default;

    // Here is the method I would like to improve
    SetOfA(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> >& data)
    {
        //do not like this loop, prefer this to be in initialization part?
        for (const auto& d : data) {
            set_of_a.insert(std::move(d->clone()));
        }
    }

private:
    std::set<std::unique_ptr <A> > set_of_a;
};
```

But is there a way to avoid this `for` loop in constructor and move the `std::set` construction into initialization part?

Comment: Note that `std::move()` is redundant there. `clone()` returns a prvalue.

Comment: I believe you're out of luck, unless you count "write a separate cloning function for vectors" as a solution.

Comment: C++20 `std::views::transform` comes close, but then `std::set` doesn't have a constructor taking a view.

Comment: @aschepler you just need a intermediate function that calls the iterator constructor. `template <typename Container, std::range Range> Container construct(Range&& r) { return { r.begin(), r.end() }; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use Boost, here is a possible solution:

```
SetOfA(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>& data) :
    set_of_a(
        boost::make_transform_iterator(data.begin(), std::mem_fn(&A::clone)),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(data.end(),   std::mem_fn(&A::clone)))
    { }
```

Comment: @JeJo Move iterators would leave the vector elements empty. Given the discussion of `clone` and the `const` vector in the question, I don't think that's wanted here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::transform` to avoid `for` loop to insert values in a `std::set`.

```
SetOfA(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> >&data) 
{
   std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), std::inserter(set_of_a, set_of_a.begin()), [](auto& a){return a->clone();});
 // or better
 //std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), std::inserter(set_of_a, set_of_a.begin()), std::mem_fn(&A::clone));
}
```

It compiles with C++14 and above. Please find tested version of it here *https://godbolt.org/z/jzvaKovn7*.

And to put the whole stuff in initialization part, you could use a lambda or a Functor, to convert data into set as shown below:

```
class SetOfA
{
    struct VectorToSetConverter
    {
        std::set<std::unique_ptr<A>> operator()  (const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> >&data) const
        {
            std::set<std::unique_ptr<A>> set_of_a;
            std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), std::inserter(set_of_a, set_of_a.begin()), std::mem_fn(&A::clone));
            return set_of_a;
        }
   };

  public:
  
    SetOfA() = default;
    SetOfA(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A> >&data)
    : set_of_a(std::move(VectorToSetConverter()(data))) // move might not be necessary
    {
    }
    
  private:

    std::set<std::unique_ptr <A> > set_of_a;
};
```

*https://godbolt.org/z/6aGPKndb6*

Comment: You are right @JeJo. I just updated my answer.

Comment: That's true. `std::make_move_iterator` could have been a better choice if data `SetOfA` constructor was pass by value.